# SSL and www - handling redirect from https://mysite to https://www.mysite

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, redirect

So this is obviously a 2x2 matrix - www and non-www, against SSL and non-SSL.

I want all traffic to be directed to SSL **and** www.

Getting `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` over to `https://www.example.com` is simple; I just add this line in the `<VirtualHost *.80>` container:

```
Redirect / https://www.example.com
```

And it works.  The problem is getting `https://example.com` over to `https://www.example.com`.  I don't have a digital certificate for `example.com` - the cert is written for `www.example.com`!

I'm thinking anything I put inside the `<VirtualHost *.443>` wrapper (Rewrite Rules etc.) won't help because the cert validity is checked first.  I'm wanting the redirect to happen BEFORE I get the scary-looking message below.  How would I do this?

[image: standard Chrome message for irregular cert]

Comment: Which OS/version do you run apache on?

Answer (score 1):

As the certificate doesn't cover `example.com`, you need a separate `VirtualHost` for your `example.com:443`. With [SNI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3) it can have another certificate for `example.com`, e.g. free certificate from Let's Encrypt. You simply can't get rid of the error without a matching certificate.

Comment: I did do a separate `VirtualHost` container with example.com:443, but of course there's no cert.  What does SNI mean?

Comment: There must be a matching certificate. *Server Name Indication* SNI is a TLS extension that enables you to have multiple certificates on a single IP address i.e. with VirtualHosts. It's explained e.g. by [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/) and [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-server-name-indication/). For millenials there's even [videos](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vzq2RPYiKL0) on YouTube.