# Redirecting of hostname to full qualified domain name with HTTPS fails

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

First off, I don't want to use rewrites.

I'm trying to redirect any call (HTTP or HTTPS) to `myserver` to the secured fully qualified domain using https at `https://myserver.fullyqualified.com`.

Here is my config

```
# Redirect all http traffic to https
<VirtualHost *:80> # line 545
  Redirect / https://myserver.fullyqualified.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> # line 549
  ServerName myserver.fullyqualified.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "conf/mycert.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/mykey.key"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443> # line 555
  ServerName myserver
  Redirect / https://myserver.fullyqualified.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine for HTTP, I can call `http://myserver` and it redirects to `https://myserver.fullyqualified.com` just fine.

However when I call `https://myserver` I get an error about the site not being secure, and it doesn't redirect to `https://myserver.fullyqualified.com` like I expect it to.

In Chrome, the error says

> This server could not prove that it is myserver; its security certificate is from myserver.fullyqualified.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

This is the output of `httpd -S`

```
*:80                   MYSERVER.fullyqualified.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:545)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myserver.fullyqualified.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:549)
         port 443 namevhost myserver.fullyqualified.com (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:549)
         port 443 namevhost myserver (C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:555)
ServerRoot: "C:/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="C:/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: SRVROOT=c:/Apache24
```

How can I redirect HTTPS traffic to the full qualified domain name?

Comment: I know that you already have an answer, but could you have added the line `ServerAlias myserver` in the first `virtualhost *:443` block instead of setting up a separate block?

Comment: @doneal24 no, because then it wouldn't redirect to the fully qualified domain name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your SSL certificate for HTTPS should have myserver inside it as a alternative name, as it seem a simple ssl error that block the redirect.

If a homemade certificate please be sure to install it into the client store before testing. You can deploy the certificate by GPO if you are into a active directory domain.

Comment: In this case yes, it is a homemade (self signed) certificate. Thanks for the idea about adding the alternate name though, didn't think of that! And yes, the certificate is installed on the client.

Comment: Adding `myserver` as an alternate name in the certificate resolved the issue

Answer (score 5):

If your cert is for `https://example.com`, the browser will not accept it to access `https://example` because the names don't match.

Unless you have self-signed certificates accepted in your browser (and those of all your clients), this can't be prevented, and you won't get any public signed certs (e.g. with Let's encrypt or any regular CA) for a hostname without a TLD.

Comment: Thank you. In my case this is not a public facing web app. Would you agree with yagmoth55's idea to add `myserver` as an alternate name in the cert?

Comment: Yes, that should work in that case.

Comment: The OP is not trying to get the browser to "accept" the domain but simply redirect it.  That said I think the problem is that since the original request is on https, the browser/Apache want to resolve the SSL FIRST before handling the redirect since the <VirtualHost> is on *.443, and this happens before the redirect.

Comment: @OliverWilliams: Redirect or rewrite happens after the connection. At this point, the names in the cert already need to match the hostname. Everything else would make TLS security worthless.

Comment: Yeah, I coincidentally posted the exact same issue just minutes ago, https://serverfault.com/questions/974994/ssl-and-www-handling-redirect-from-https-mysite-to-https-www-mysite - as long as I have http redirects working, it's highly unlikely a user will manually type in `https://nonqualified.com` in the browser.  Preventing a bad/scary UX is my main goal.

Comment: fyi @OliverWilliams Adding `myserver` to the alternate names in the certificate resolved the issue, so maybe that will help you as well.

Comment: Thanks @zero01alpha, I'm not sure I can do that though with a 3rd-party signed certificate however, I'll look into it though

Comment: @OliverWilliams You can’t do my tip with a 3rd-party signed certificate, I wrote my answer assuming it’s a self signed certificate, as I often see that scenario for like Exchange server, where a public dns name is configured for external access and a private name for internal’s access.